# read.csv appends/modifies column headings with date values

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to read a csv file into R that has date values in some of the colum headings.

As an example, the data file looks something like this:

```
ID  Type   1/1/2001  2/1/2001  3/1/2001  4/1/2011
A   Supply       25        35        45        55  
B   Demand       26        35        41        22
C   Supply       25        35        44        85  
D   Supply       24        39        45        75  
D   Demand       26        35        41        22
```

...and my read.csv logic looks like this

```
dat10 <- read.csv("c:\data.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",",as.is=TRUE)
```

The read.csv works fine except it modifies the name of the colums with dates as follows:

```
x1.1.2001  x2.1.2001  x3.1.2001  x4.1.2001
```

Is there a way to prevent this, or a easy way to correct afterwards?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `check.names=FALSE`.  But be aware that `1/1/2001` et al are syntactically invalid names, therefore they may cause you some headaches.

Answer (score 3):

You can always change the column names using the `colnames` function. For example,

```
colnames(dat10) = gsub("\\.", "/", colnames(dat10))
```

However, having slashes in your column names isn't a particularly good idea. You can always change them just before you print out the table or when you create a graph.

Comment: Very nice, but I believe _my_ way is the easy way. ;-)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich True, but I get bonus points for using a regular expression ;)